# CGRectIntersectsRect with 2 UIImageViews does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, cgrect

I have a problem.

Briefly: `CGRectIntersectsRect(object1.frame, object2.frame)` placed in `UIViewController` does not work for object1 and object2 created in different classes (Class1 and Class2). I only can change their coordinates like `object1.center.x`, and `object1.frame.size.width = 0` (I guess this is why `CGRectIntersection` function does not work). These objects just came through each other.

As I understand it may be connected with protocol/delegating, but I haven't found any sufficient information how to be in my situation.

**Platform.m** (my class for creating a platform in the ViewController)

```
@implementation Platform

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        platformView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
        platformView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"platform.png"];

        [self addSubview:platformView];

    }
    return self;
}
```

**ViewController.m** (in the @interface there are Platform *platform; Kelvin *kelvin;)

```
-(void)addPlatform
   {
    platform = [[Platform alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(initialPlatformX, (500 -    arc4random()%200), 200, 10)];
    [self.view addSubview:platform];
   }

    **if (!CGRectIntersectsRect(kelvin.frame, platform.frame)) {
        NSLog(@"%f", platform.frame.size.width);
    }**
```

Comment: BTW, you don't show the creation of `kelvin`. Is it a subview of the same view that `platform` is? If they're not subviews of the same view, you have to convert the frames to the same coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is confusing and hard to follow.

This sentence, for example, is a total mystery to me:

> As I understand it may be connected with protocol/delegating, but i
>   haven't found any sufficient information how to be in my situation.

Delegation? Huh? Rectangles are not objects. Delegation is a design pattern for objects. How is that relevant here? (Answer: Very likely it isn't relevant at all.)

Moving on, though, here are a few things to consider:

2 views' frames will only use the same coordinate system if they are both subviews of the same view. So are your platform and your "kelvin" view subviews of the same view (It looks like you add platform directly to the view controller's content view, so is your "kelvin" view also a subview of the view controller's content view?)

Also, you make reference to `object1.frame.size.width = 0`

The CGRectIntersectsRect function checks to see if any pixels of the 2 rectangles overlap. If either of your rectangles has either a height or a width of 0, it's empty, and can't intersect with anything.

Comment: Thank you! that was my mistake, these two objects, "platform" and "kelvin" are subviews of the same view, but not directly, and I placed "Kelvin" through CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height) using x and y coordinates here, and accordingly that later they had different coordinates while intersecting. Now I changed initial coordinates for them both to 0, 0 and it works! =)

Answer (score 0):

In `initWithFrame`, you are adding a `UIImageView` subview to `Platform` using the `frame` of `Platform`. That is incorrect. For example, if you add `PlatForm` at `CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100)`, you'll then be adding the image view at `CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100)` within `Platform` (which is `CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100)` within the original view).

So, instead, I think you want to make a `CGRect` that starts at `0, 0` (or use the `bounds` of `Platform`, not its `frame`):

```
@implementation Platform

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        platformView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
        platformView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"platform.png"];

        [self addSubview:platformView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

By the way, just to be safe, you might also want to set `clipsToBounds` to `YES`, so that if you ever change `contentMode` to something that doesn't scale to fit, you don't have to worry about the image bleeding over its bounds.